# Formula for analytic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

In [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/) (third under double infinite series) they list the following formula.

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{k,j} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{j} a_{k, j-k}$$

Is this true and how does one prove it?

Comment: The same terms appear on both sides: of course if these are real numbers, one needs the series to be absolutely convergent.

Comment: $(a_{0,0} + a_{0,1} + a_{0,2}) +  (a_{1,0} + a_{1,1} + a_{1,2}) + (a_{2,0} + a_{2,1} + a_{2,2}) =  (a_{0,0}) + (a_{0,1} + a_{1,0}) + (a_{0,2} + a_{1,2} + a_{2,0})$

Comment: Notice that on the right hand side the indices add up to a fixed number in each group. $(k + j - k = j)$

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an analogy here.
Imagine painting a rectangular wall. You can cover the wall in many ways.

One way is to paint it column by column :

[image]
On $xy$ plane, this represents a situation when you keep $x$ constant and vary $y$ in each column.

Alternatively you could also go like this :

[image]

On $xy$ plane, this represents a situation when you keep $x+y$ constant in each slanted line.